# Why is the only thing my Studio can craft a Dragon Idol?

Tags: happy-street

I've just unlocked the mountain in Happy Street, and received a quest to craft some cut stone.

Great!

...So why is the only item available for me to craft the Dragon Idol?

I even created one in the thoughts that maybe you had to build one to get access to the rest of the items, but there was no change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level up! At level 9 you can only craft that. Once I reached level 10 I could craft 2 more items. And to craft cut stone I'm assuming you have to use the actual craft workshop not the studio.

Comment: No all stonework is done in the studio. Aside from cut moonstone.